# Why was my edit rejected and someone else's same edit approved

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I edit this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14493764/3247497 . My edit was rejected and the same edit was made by someone else. The answer is old too. So, my edit was rejected and it was edited again.

Comment: [This would be why.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6664173) The user whose name is now on the answer as editor selected the option "Reject and Edit" when reviewing your edit. No, they did not make the same edit. It looks like they rejected yours for over-use of the backtick for inline code, but agreed the code block needed formatting. Backticks should only be used to highlight actual code in a sentence: "I tried using `foo(bar)`..." is right, for example, but highlighting "asyncTalk" with it looks incorrect to me (but I don't know the technology, so...).

Comment: Because the user who finally edited it found your edit to be insufficient.

Comment: @Kendra [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is the name of a class (and thus code), so it is entirely appropriate to put in code formatting.  But I do think that repeating it throughout a paragraph can be excessive.

Comment: @JasonMArcher Exactly why I didn't put an answer. :) Being unfamiliar with the technology, I wasn't sure if it was appropriate or not, but it did indeed look excessive. Thanks for the clarification there!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The edit was made by the [reviewer that rejected your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6664173). They picked the *Reject and Edit* option, which includes a veto rejection to allow for the reviewer edit to be applied.

It appears the reviewer did not like your additional backtick use in your edit. I am a little puzzled at that; at best I'd have **accepted** your edit, perhaps with an additional edit, but your edit looked appropriate to me.