# Question asker rejected my edit suggestion but someone else made the same edit

Tags: discussion, tags

Note: This is not same question as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281860/why-was-my-edit-rejected-and-someone-elses-same-edit-approved)

I have a problem with the system, I think.

So in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922472/avoid-keys-reach-application) question, I [edited the tag and removed `C#`](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17167327) but the user who asked question rejected my suggestion with following comment:

> C# tag was on porpouse because the modification can possibly be in the DLL (which is coded in C#)

Then I noticed that some other person did the same edit because he didn't needed anyone's approval as he has "**reputations**". isn't it unfair for us with low reputations? I asked for one thing and got rejected while someone else did the same without any problem.

Comment: According to OP's rejection message "C# tag was on porpouse because the modification can possibly be in the DLL (which is coded in C#)"... So if approved the change would indeed be unfair to "with low reputation", but in a way opposite what you imply in this post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> isn't it unfair for us with low reputations?

I wouldn't call it unfair, but rather just a little unfortunate. There are two reasons why this happened:

1. The OP of a question can approve or reject any suggested edit.

   This makes total sense, since they have the ability to edit their own question however they want anyway. Note that they can also rollback any other edits made by users with > 2k rep. Every now and again, this causes situations where the OP will reject or rollback good edits, but that's not the norm.
2. Anyone with > 2000 reputation points gets to make edits without them having to go through the review queue.

   This also makes sense, especially considering how many low quality and bad edits are constantly being suggested (way too many of these also get approved, which is a much bigger issue than what we are discussing here). Having a threshold that is used to determine whether edits need to be reviewed or not helps with this issue.

The question now doesn't have the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag any more, which is the most important thing. You could have gotten 2 reputation points, but you didn't, even though the edit wasn't bad. It's not the end of the world, and certainly rare enough to not require any changes to the system.

Comment: i can understand that but it just feels bad because my stats are changed and I have now one more **"rejected"** suggestion in my profile even if the suggestion was correct

Comment: According to OP's rejection comment "just a little unfortunate" is understatement and edit clearly conflicted with they intention. (And possibly the other removal of C# tag should have been rolled back by OP too - I've added comment along this lines to the original post)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The OP needs to make that a lot clearer in the question itself rather than just adding the c# tag. Currently the question has no real sign that they are also trying to modify the DLL. It shows an attempt at a VB application that makes use of the given DLL and therefore *seems* to be asking how to make the VB app work. Just because I'm using a library coded in another language doesn't necessarily mean that that language is essential to my question. If they clarify that they also intend to modify the dll  then c# could definitely be a valid tag.

Comment: Sad thing that anyone even bother to TRY to help me with the problem I have. Despite my bad comunication (I'm not good at english at all, making my major effort to be clear), all the help point to make me follow some "rules". I asked because I didn't know how to accomplish what I needed, can be modifing MY code or the code I used (again, which is in C#, as I say in te comment of the reject). If 'reputation' for making edits is more important than try to help, thanks! you are doing it great.

Comment: @LogoS When someone comes across your question they can't see your explanation of why you rejected a previous suggested edit. In fact, the link to the suggestion wasn't even included in this meta question until after I had posted this answer. That's what I'm trying to say in my comment above. If you are also attempting to change the DLL that is perfectly fine and c# is a valid tag in that case, but you need to include this information in the question itself for people to be able to realize that they don't need to edit out the c# tag. ...

Comment: ... I can't help you with your specific question because I'm nowhere near qualified enough to answer anything VB related. But that also not what we are discussing in this meta question anyway. I'm also afraid I don't really know what you mean by *"If 'reputation' for making edits is more important than try to help, thanks! you are doing it great."*

Comment: C# tag was there for a reason, if all people qualified to answer about a modification in C# (that is obiously will be made to the DLL) didn't want to TRY to help, and instead worries more about "what is the C# tag doing there", then I understand that is more important deleting the tag that helping me somehow. But don't worry about my question (awfully done, with all their errors and bad tags), I marked it for deletion, so no one have to 'work on it' ever again.

Comment: *If 'reputation' for making edits is more important than try to help* - The point of editing a question is to try to help. In this case the tag edit was incorrect but it was not done maliciously. Note that you can always roll back an incorrect edit no matter who makes it.